# -moz-linear-gradient not working on IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm using gradient as a background:

```
-moz-linear-gradient(center bottom , #E8E8E8 0%, #F2F2F1 50%) repeat scroll 0 0 #F5F5F4;
```

This is not showing in IE, I haven't found links or anything about what I need to do if the browser is IE.

Any ideas on how to handle this?

Comment: This is a joke, right? An attempt at trolling?

Comment: `-moz-` is a prefix specific to Mozilla. Removing the prefix should work (in the future) but for IE10 you need `-ms-` prefix. IE9 and below require something else entirely.

Comment: Sorry Williham Totland, this was not meant to be a joke =(
Thanks Yotaware.

Comment: Another reason why the Web would be a better place without vendor prefixes.

Comment: @Yotaware: No, `linear-gradient()` is only supported in IE10+.

Comment: @BoltClock: I disagree: Vendor prefixes are a well documented feature of CSS; this is an issue of not reading the documentation. The Web might be a better place without people who don't read the documentation, but it would also be a far more desolate and empty place.

Comment: @BoltClock Ye I should have checked first.

Comment: Not only that but ie9 needs even more code to support...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might be interested in reading this: [prefix or posthack](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prefix-or-posthack/).

As the comments state `-moz-` is the vendor specific prefix for Mozilla.

If you're interested in cross browser gradients, I find the easiest way is to use a [gradient generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) to sort through all the different implementations and prefixes.

Answer (score 6):

this is the gradient code for all browsers

```
   /* IE10 */ 
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top left, #FFFFFF 0%, #00A3EF 100%);

/* Mozilla Firefox */ 
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top left, #FFFFFF 0%, #00A3EF 100%);

/* Opera */ 
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top left, #FFFFFF 0%, #00A3EF 100%);

/* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */ 
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0, #FFFFFF), color-stop(1, #00A3EF));

/* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */ 
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, #FFFFFF 0%, #00A3EF 100%);

/* Proposed W3C Markup */ 
background-image: linear-gradient(top left, #FFFFFF 0%, #00A3EF 100%);
```

you can use this site to generate gradient [ultimate css generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

it's not supported in IE9 so you can make a little section of the gradient and repeat it

Comment: it's not supported in IE9 so you can make a little section of the gradient and repeat it

Answer (score 0):

Linear gradient drawing via CSS3 is still experimental. The CSS function you provided is Mozilla specific, as indicated by the `-moz` prefix. But not all is lost, as Microsoft has their own implementation as well ([-ms-linear-gradient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453527.aspx))

Upon cursory glance, it appears you can simply copy that line and simply change `-moz` to `-ms` with near perfect compatibility. Refer to the documentation if you run into any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `gradient` filter for IE:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#ffffff'); /* for IE */
```